# Getting WriteConflict when trying to use mongo transactions (v4.0.12)

Tags: mongodb, scala, reactivemongo

My transaction is pretty simple, it looks like this:

```
  def updateReportTransac(metadata: Metadata, expensesIds: List[String], pairings: List[Pairing])(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[Report] = for {
    dbWithSession <- collection.db.startSession()
    dbWithTx <- dbWithSession.startTransaction(None)
    reportCollection = dbWithTx.collection[BSONCollection](collection.name) 

    _ <- firstUpdate(reportCollection, metadata, expensesIds)
    rep <- secondUpdate(reportCollection, metadata, pairings)

    _ <- dbWithTx.commitTransaction()

    _ <- dbWithSession.endSession()
  } yield rep

  def firstUpdate(collection: BSONCollection, metadata: Metadata, expensesIds: List[String]): Future[UpdateWriteResult] = {
    collection.update.one(
      q = BSONDocument(
        "metadata.companyId" -> metadata.companyId,
        "metadata.reportId" -> metadata.reportId,
        "metadata.workloadId" -> metadata.workloadId),
      u = BSONDocument("$set" -> BSONDocument("expenses.$[elem].paired" -> true)),
      upsert = false, multi = false, collation = None,
      arrayFilters = Seq(BSONDocument("elem.id" -> BSONDocument("$in" -> expensesIds)))
    )
  }

  def secondUpdate(collection: BSONCollection, reportMetadata: Metadata, pairings: List[Pairing]): Future[Report] = {
    collection.findAndUpdate(
      selector = BSONDocument(
        "metadata.companyId" -> metadata.companyId,
        "metadata.reportId" -> metadata.reportId,
        "metadata.workloadId" -> metadata.workloadId),
      update = BSONDocument("$addToSet" -> BSONDocument("pairings" -> BSONDocument("$each" -> pairings))),
      fetchNewObject = true, upsert = false, sort = None, fields = None, bypassDocumentValidation = false, writeConcern = WriteConcern.Acknowledged, maxTime = None, collation = None, arrayFilters = Nil)
      .map(_.result[Report].getOrElse {
        throw new NoSuchElementException
      })
  }
```

I'm not sure why, but when I run it with multiple threads I get this error:

```
 error: CommandError[code=112, errmsg=WriteConflict, doc: {
  "errorLabels": [
    "TransientTransactionError"
  ],
  "operationTime": Timestamp(1595840406, 194),
  "ok": 0.0,
  "errmsg": "WriteConflict",
  "code": 112,
  "codeName": "WriteConflict",
  "$clusterTime": {
    "clusterTime": Timestamp(1595840406, 194),
    "signature": {
      "hash": BSONBinary(GenericBinarySubtype, size = 20),
      "keyId": NumberLong(6805543085452296193)
    }
  }
}]
```

Comment: Indicating versions would be useful

Comment: @cchantep mongodb v4.0.12, reactivemongo 0.18.8-play27 (i know there are newer versions but cant change it at the moment)

Comment: Then as there are fixes in new versions ... Also have a look at https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-36428 and https://developpaper.com/solve-the-problem-of-mongodb-transaction-writeconflict/

Comment: @cchantep so if I cant move to later version you suggest to not use transaction ?

Comment: If you are performing concurrent reads and writes on the same data, you should be using withTransaction api which assists with writing the proper code to handle write conflicts.

Comment: @cchantep can you please tell me which version of reactive will fix this writeConcern issue? (with mongodb 4)

Comment: There is no issue confirm at driver level there.